# How to write a Python ABC with a concrete initializer in python 2.6 to 3.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing, abc

## The Context

I have a python application with a relatively involved class hierarchy. It needs to work with python 2.6 up to python 3.5 (a big range, I know!), and I've been having particular problems with ABCs.
I'm using the `six` library's `with_metaclass` to ease some of the hurt, but it's still problematic.

One particular set of classes has been giving me trouble. Here's what it looks like in a simplified form:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from six import with_metaclass

# SomeParentABC is another ABC, in case it is relevant
class MyABC(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, SomeParentABC)):
    def __init__(self, important_attr):
        self.important_attr = important_attr
    def gamma(self):
         self.important_attr += ' gamma'

class MyChild1(MyABC):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyChild1(imporant_attr=%s)" % important_attr
    def alpha(self):
         self.important_attr += ' alpha'

class MyChild2(MyABC):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyChild2(imporant_attr=%s)" % important_attr
    def beta(self):
         self.important_attr += ' beta'
```

There's a lot of `gamma` like functions bundled in `MyABC`, and a few subclass specific functions like `alpha` and `beta`. I want all of the subclasses of `MyABC` to inherit the same `__init__` and `gamma` attributes, and then pile on their own specific characteristics.

## The Problem

The issue is that in order for `MyChild1` and `MyChild2` to share code for `__init__`, `MyABC` needs to have a concrete initializer.
In Python 3, everything is working just fine, but in Python 2, when the initializer is concrete, I fail to get `TypeErrors` when instantiating `MyABC`.

I have a segment in my testsuite that looks something like this

```
def test_MyABC_really_is_abstract():
    try:
        MyABC('attr value')
    # ideally more sophistication here to get the right kind of TypeError,
    # but I've been lazy for now
    except TypeError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False
```

Somehow, in Python 2.7 (I assume 2.6, but haven't bothered to check) this test is failing.

`MyABC` doesn't have any other abstract properties, but it isn't meaningful to instantiate a class that has `gamma` without also having either `alpha` or `beta`.
For now, I've been getting by with a DRY violation by just duplicating the `__init__` function in `MyChild1` and `MyChild2`, but as time goes on this is becoming more and more burdensome.

How can I give a Python 2 ABC a concrete initializer without making it instantiable, while maintaining Python 3 compatibility?
In other words, I want trying to instantiate `MyABC` to throw `TypeError`s in Python 2 and Python 3, but it only throws them in Python 3.

### with_metaclass

I believe it is relevant to see the code for `with_metaclass` here.
This is provided under the existing License and Copyright of the `six` project, (c) 2010-2014 Bejamin Peterson

```
def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):
    """Create a base class with a metaclass."""
    # This requires a bit of explanation: the basic idea is to make a dummy
    # metaclass for one level of class instantiation that replaces itself with
    # the actual metaclass.
    class metaclass(meta):
        def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
            return meta(name, bases, d)
    return type.__new__(metaclass, 'temporary_class', (), {})
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback when the `TypeError` is thrown in Python 2?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what you're asking for here. There is no `TypeError` thrown in Python2. That is exactly the problem: I want one to be thrown because `MyABC` is meant to be abstract.

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear then; you expect it to be thrown but isn't.

Comment: That's handled by `type.__new__`; I don't see any overrides here for `__new__`; is `SomeParentABC` doing that perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've just edited the question to include the `with_metaclass` code, which does edit `__new__`. I admit to that it gives me a headache to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `six.with_metaclass()` meta class may be incompatible with ABCs as it overrides `type.__new__`; this could interfere with the normal procedure for testing for concrete methods.

Try using the [`@six.add_metaclass()` class decorator](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.add_metaclass) instead:

from abc import ABCMeta
from six import add_metaclass

```
@add_metaclass(ABCMeta)
class MyABC(SomeParentABC):
    def __init__(self, important_attr):
        self.important_attr = important_attr
    def gamma(self):
         self.important_attr += ' gamma'
```

Demo:

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
>>> from six import add_metaclass
>>> @add_metaclass(ABCMeta)
... class MyABC(object):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def gamma(self): pass
... 
>>> MyABC()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyABC with abstract methods gamma
```

Note that you do need to have *abstract methods without concrete implementations* for the `TypeError` to be raised!

Comment: This is definitely help if the right direction, but I'm still able to instantiate a class which has used `@add_metaclass(ABCMeta)`. Specifically, if I decorate with `add_metaclass` and inherit from `object`, then `MyABC('some value')` still works.

Comment: @sirosen: I accidentally left in the `with_metaclass()` call; removed now.

Comment: @sirosen: that said, I am having trouble reproducing your case with `six.with_metaclass`.

Comment: I don't think the `with_metaclass` usage was the issue though. In python 2.7 and 3.2 (my local testing versions), I am still able to instantiate MyABC if it is identical to the above, but inherits directly from `object`. Does it need to have an abstract property or abstract method to raise the `TypeError`? (Also, thanks so much for taking so much time and effort on this!)

Comment: @sirosen: yes, I was assuming your *parent* ABC meta had those.